# how to hide or remove UIbutton from headerview

Tags: iphone, uibutton, tableview

I have a button in headerview of my tableview, its woking fine as well, but problem i am having is: When I want to hide that button on click of another button. How can I achieve this? I have already tried 
[deletebutton  removeFromSuperview];

where deleteButton is my buttons name.

Here is what I am doing

`-(void)PutTableinEditMode{`

DeleteButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

DeleteButton.frame=CGRectMake(10,1, 65, 25);

[DeleteButton setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

DeleteButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

[DeleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(DeleteMultipleToDos) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[headerView addSubview:DeleteButton];

}

Then I m having another function as below from where i want to hide this DeleteButton

-(void)DoneEditing
{

```
DeleteButton.hidden=YES;

[DeleteButton removeFromSuperview];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the it working actually [DeleteButton removeFromSuperView] is working .. problem was that the first method PutTableinEditMode was being called from somewhere else also, so i simply took a bool variable and on basis of its value added and removed the delete button
:)

Thanks guys for helping though :) 
Ifeel so stupid to make such a silly mistake :)

Comment: Good News ! Mark one of the answer as correct of you will have a low 'Accept' rate and your questions will "suddenly" not being answered :-D

Answer (score 1):

deletebutton.hidden = YES

Answer (score 1):

if any of those two solution (`removeFromSuperview` and `hidden`) do not work, then you certainly don't have the right reference to your button.  I guess your using nib files to define your views ? Then be sure the member deleteButton is well "linked" to the actual button. (i.e. verify using debug that your deleteButton var is not null)

Comment: No, my button is not coming from a nib file, I am creating it through code, its defined in .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Can u try and change the Text of that button because i'm thinking your sending messages to nil objects.